# SignalR client execution of code after connection is eastablished

Tags: javascript, signalr

I want to execute code after successful connection to SignalR hub has been established from the client.

Right now this is achieved by adding code in `done` method but it is not working properly. The same in .NET code is achieved by await method.

Is there any way to handle in SignalR client (javascript, angular JS)?

Comment: I've retagged your question with [tag:javascript] since it sounds like that's the kind of SignalR client you're talking about. The [tag:signalr.client] tag is for the "Async signaling library for .NET applications" which doesn't sound like what you're looking for. If that was incorrect, feel free to undo (or rollback) my edit.

Comment: You'll probably need to add better detail for "it is not working properly"... and post some code. Check out how to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).